# How can I filter my fetched data and load into tableview?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, filter

I am using Firebase database. I fetched the data and want to filter and display only the information that matches the users selection.

I have used a conditional statement to look for the matched value and append the list, however, I cannot get the table to load. When I print the variable, it prints 0. Need help thanks.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    projectlbl.text = "Brand: \((repair?.brand)!) Model: \((repair?.modelNumber)!)"

    refResources = Database.database().reference().child("resources");


    let selectedProject = "\((repair?.modelNumber)!)"


    //observing the data changes
    refResources!.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self.resourceList.removeAll()

            //iterating through all the values
            for resources in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let resourceObject = resources.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let id  = resourceObject?["id"]
                let RSSSubCat  = resourceObject?["RSSSubCat"]
                let RSSBrand = resourceObject?["RSSBrand"]
                let RSSModelNumber = resourceObject?["RSSModelNumber"]
                let RSSTitle = resourceObject?["RSSTitle"]
                let RSSUrl = resourceObject?["RSSUrl"]

                //creating resource object with model and fetched values
                let resource = resourceModel(id: id as! String?, RSSSubCat: RSSSubCat as! String?, RSSBrand: RSSBrand as! String?, RSSModelNumber: RSSModelNumber as! String?, RSSTitle: RSSTitle as! String?, RSSUrl: RSSUrl as! String?)

                //appending it to list
                print(snapshot.childrenCount)

                if selectedProject == resource.RSSModelNumber {
                    print(selectedProject)
                    self.resourceList.append(resource)
                    self.diagResTable.reloadData()
                } else {
                    return
                }

            }

            //reloading the tableview
            self.diagResTable.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Your mistake is that If the first item of `resources` doesn't match the condition it exits the function with `return`. Rather than fetching all objects and filter them use a predicate to fetch only objects which match the predicate.

Comment: let selectedModelNumber = (self.refResources?.child("RSSModelNumber").queryEqual(toValue: selectedProject))


I am trying to implement this predicate but I am not sure how. I have been combing over firebase docs and I still confused.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebase but **every** serious database provides fetching data filtered by a predicate.

Comment: I got it thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change the listener... Simple yet overlooked.

```
       let selectedModelNumber = (self.refResources?.queryOrdered(byChild: "RSSModelNumber").queryEqual(toValue: selectedProject))


    //observing the data changes
    selectedModelNumber!.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```